# In Google Spreadsheets, how to ignore empty cells in conditional formatting?

Tags: formatting, conditional-statements, spreadsheet

I'm trying to format a spreadsheet to change cell color to green/red if the result was predicted correctly/incorrectly. For the correct one, I just went with =(cell with the results)=(cell where the prediction is) and it's all fine, but for the incorrect ones, I had to do NOT(same formula I just wrote) and it tries to color every cell red, even those that haven't had a prediction typed in yet, because there can be multiple bad outcomes. How to ignore conditional formatting before the result is typed into the "result" cell?

Answer (score 3):

The `ISBLANK` function returns true if the referenced cell is blank, and false otherwise. You can use this in the custom formula to require that both the value is incorrect and the cell is not blank. That is,

`=AND([your current formula], NOT(ISBLANK([cell with the results])))`

Alternatively, you could add another formatting rule. There's an "Is empty" option for conditional formatting, and the formatting style would be no color. Make sure to put this rule above the red rule.